# Selecting jquery elements with brackets []

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this work

```
$('div.note')[0].removeClass('hidden');
```

I get this error from firebug:

```
TypeError: note.removeClass is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('div.note')[0]` gives you a javascript object, not a jQuery object, and removeClass is a jQuery method. You need to convert it to a jQuery object before using jQuery methods.

Try this,

```
$($('div.note')[0]).removeClass('hidden');
```

or

```
$('div.note').eq(0).removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Haha, awesome, is there a logical reason why that works and what I tried doesn't?

Comment: @Costa Because you unwrap the jQuery object and reference it as a javascript element. This means you cannot apply jQuery logic to the element.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not strict on the bracket usage, using `.eq()` is much more streamlined.

```
$('div.note').eq(0).removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basically, think of each jQuery call as giving you an object that looks like this:

```
var myPosts = $(".posts");

// To help make sense of it, myPosts looks something like this.
myPosts === {
   elements : [ /* all of your returned elements */ ]
   helpfulMethod : function () { for (element in elements) { /* .... */ } },
   otherHelpfulMethod : function () { for (element in elements) { /*...*/ } }
}
```

If you said:

```
var element = myPosts.elements[0];
element.otherHelpfulMethod();
```

it would spit errors at you.

The way it gets around having the .element addition is by calling the array as "this", after the fact.

You could also do:

```
for (i in arr; ....) {
    this[i] = arr[i];
}
```

and get the same effect.

So calling myPosts[0] just gets you the HTML element.
Then you either need to wrap that in a jQuery object to use the helper methods, or you need to use the jQuery helper function, to access that particular element.